# converting a date format in java

Tags: java

**I have a date value:** - `2019-09-30T00:00:00.000+05:30`

**I want to convert into the format -** `dd MMM yyyy`

**I have the code:**

```
public static String parseDateAndTimeStringCust(String datestring) {
        if(datestring.length()>=10){
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(dateFormat2.parse(datestring));
                return fDate;
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return datestring;
    }
```

**Analysis:**
My `dateFormat2` I am using is wrong

**Question:**

1. What is the correct data format i have to use so that I can get the
   result in the format `dd MMM yyyy`
2. What is the proper reference I can use in future to build such date
   formats

Comment: Please don't use the obsolete `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes. Use the newer Java Date & Time API from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: "My dateFormat2 I am using is wrong" - what exactly is the problem you're facing? Do you have to use `SimpleDateFormat` (in that case use the Javadoc on that class as a reference) or would switching to the new date api be an option (recommended)?

Comment: "2019-09-30T00:00:00.000+05:30" - have a look at that date: there is no space between the date and the time but a  `T`, it contains a millisecond part and it contains a timezone offset. So the format you're using to parse that should reflect that, e.g. something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should use classes from the `java.time` package.**

This is what you're looking for.

```
String str = "2019-09-30T00:00:00.000+05:30";
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(str);
String out = dt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy"));
System.out.println(out);
```

Note that the actual output depends on your locale, but then you could supply the `Locale` as the second argument to [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-).

Also note that the single-argument version of [`OffsetDateTime.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) implies the `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` format.

Furthermore, whether the actual output of abovementioned method is accurate, depends on how you want to handle the timezone offset, i.e. whether you want to convert it to UTC or ignore it. For instance, the timestamp `2019-09-30T00:00:00.000+05:30` actually falls on the 29th of September if converted to UTC (the time is then 2019-09-29T18:30:00.000Z).

#### `DateTimeFormatter`

The documentation of the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class contains detailed information about the formatting symbols and how they are parsed. There are many predefined formats for well-known and commonly used patterns, for example [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) conforming with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String parseDateAndTimeStringCust(String datestring) {
        Date dataFormated = null;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try {
                dataFormated = dateFormat.parse(datestring);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        return dataFormated.toString();
}
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice. See modern solution in Answer by MC Emperor.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following line:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

To:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.